# How to add attribute in generated code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, joomla

I have a code

```
FoxHtmlElem::create('div')
    ->attr('id', $current->getBoxId())
    ->classes("fox-item fox-item-submit fox-item-submit-{$current->get('alignment')} control-group")
    ->classes($current->get('classes'))
        ->append(FoxFormRender::render('label_collapsed'))
        ->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('div')
            ->classes('controls')
                ->attr('style', "{$current->getStyleWidth()}{$current->getStyleHeight()}")
        ->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('button')
            ->classes('btn btn-success submit-button')
            ->tooltip($current->get('submit.tooltip'))
            ->attr('type', 'submit')
        ->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('span')
        ->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('span')
            ->classes($current->getIconClass('submit'))
            ->attr('style', $current->getIconStyle('submit'))
            ->text($current->get('submit.label')))))
            ->conditional($current->get('reset.enable'), function () use($current)
{
    return FoxHtmlElem::create('button')
        ->classes('btn btn-danger reset-button')
        ->tooltip($current->get('reset.tooltip'))
        ->attr('type', 'reset')
        ->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('span')
        ->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('span')
        ->classes($current->getIconClass('reset'))
        ->attr('style', $current->getIconStyle('reset'))
        ->text($current->get('reset.label'))));
}))->show();
```

This code generates html

```
<div id="fox-m138-submit-box" class="fox-item fox-item-submit fox-item-submit-fields control-group">
    <span class="control-label collapsed"></span>
<div class="controls">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit-button">
        <span>
            <span>Отправить</span>
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I need to add attribute to the button:

```
onclick="yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('ORDER'); return true;"
```

It is joomla fox contact form. Sorry for automated code. I copied and pasted it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wild guess, add this

```
->attr('onclick', 'yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal("ORDER"); return true;')
```

after the below code

```
->attr('type', 'reset')
```

Comment: I just tried the same before ask a question. The page did'n load. But now i copied youк code and it works. I think i made a mistake somewhere )) Thank you

Comment: mark this as a answer if it solves your problem !! Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Use the `click()` function.

```
$(element).click(function(){});
```

I have never used Joomla, but it should be fine to use jQuery for this.